# C++ linking with another libc with g++ - Specifying the right crt file

Tags: c++, g++, cross-compiling

I'm trying to compile my c++ code with another libc with g++. 
To do that, I used the rpath option to provide the path to the new libc.
I have also provided the dynamic-linker option to provide the corresponding linker. 
The problem is that I'm getting this error:

```
path_to_old_libc/crt1.o: In function `_start': undefined reference to `__libc_csu_fini'
```

Thus, I also have to give the path to the new crt file located at path_to_new_libc 
The problem is that I don't see any option in the manual that would allow to do that. I though about the `nostartupfile` or `nostdlib` options, but that would just ignore the crt file which is not what I want.

So far, the compilation looks like that:

```
g++ -Wl,--dynamic-linker=/.../.../.../glibc-2.22/build/elf/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 -Wl,-rpath,/buildroot/output/build/glibc-2.22/build ...
```

Therefore, I'm looking for a way to add the right crt file.

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: Just guessing, you can directly treat `crt1.o` as a normal `.o` file.

Comment: This guy use `clang++`, and he directly use the `crt1.o`. https://blogs.gentoo.org/gsoc2016-native-clang/2016/05/06/build-a-gnu-free-c-program-on-gentoo/